# how to remove local machine folder path from published application dll

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, msbuild, iis-7.5, publish

I published one web application in IIS7.5
i followed below steps

1. in VS2008 i used published web application option
2. after that i hosted publish folder in IIS 7.5 every thing working fine.

I am using log4net for error log system now when there is error in application log4net is logging error message but showing local folder path in log file.

for e.g if my code is in folder c:\code\ and hosted application in other machine d:\app\ then in error message i am getting path c:\code{filename}\ error line

my question is how to remove this local reference while publishing application on remote server?

Comment: Yogesh did you find solution to this?  I am experiencing similar issue when one of our apps from production server throws Server Error '/' Application error.

Comment: remove pdb file from live server